# ansible yum install command

Tags: linux, ansible

ansible all -m yum -a "name=java-openjdk state=present install_root=/opt/"

I am getting following error
127.0.0.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}

I can run a playbook like below
ansible-playbook --connection=local --inventory 127.0.0.1, teamcity.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you are using whatever connection is specified in your inventory. 
The second example you specify "connection=local".

Without seeing your inventory and playbook I can't be sure what the best solution is. You could make sure the entry in your hosts file uses the local connection:

```
 examplehost ansible_connection=local
```